# Go how to use cookiejar for multiple requests?

Tags: authentication, go, web-scraping, cookies, csrf

I'm trying to make a cli for a site that has csrf, needing the csrf token to be sent on headers and on a form.

I can't seem to understand net/http.Client or net/http/cookieJar

This its even good practice? There's a better way of doing csrf login on Go ?

Thx in advance ^v^

This its my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var (
    httpClient = &http.Client{}
)

func main() {
    jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    httpClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
        Jar:     jar,
    }
    requestURL := "https://example.com/"

    res, err := httpClient.Get(requestURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(res.Cookies())
    // stdout: cookie as expected

    u := &url.URL{}
    u.Parse(requestURL)

    log.Println(httpClient.Jar.Cookies(u))
    // stdout: []

    form := make(url.Values)

    /* ... */

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, requestURL, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("client: could not create request: %s\n", err)
    }

    res, err = httpClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(req)
    // stdout: cookie as expected
}
```

Comment: Cookies are saved for and served for the same site. Making requests to different sites will not share the cookies, that would be a major security issue! If you do need to serve the same cookies, either create your own CookieJar implementation, or "mirror" the needed cookies.

Comment: Also do note that `u.Parse(requestURL)` does not change `u`, it parses `requestURL` **in the context of `u`**, but it does not change `u`, it returns the parsed URL. Meaning the cookies are saved for `example.com`, and `u` remains an empty URL, obviously `Jar.Cookies(u)` will not return cookies saved for the `example.com` site. Likely you want `u, err := url.Parse(requestURL)`.

Comment: LOL that was it, thank you very much, novice mistake